# Run executable *.exe file via R

Tags: r, cmd

I have a list of files that need to execute using a *.exe file. I am currently using windows cmd and use below command line (after changing the working directory)

```
CAMCL.exe -sim *.lo
```

the *.lo file consists of model parameters and data. I want to use Rstudio and use XML package to change some model parameters through a pre-defined distribution, and execute each of those files through Rstudio rather windows command line interactively.

Question is related to if I create a list of *.lo files with changes using XML package,  can it execute using -sim command using CAMCL.exe within R studio

Comment: I think you can do what you need using `system`, `system2`, or perhaps the `processx` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to modify the `.lo` files, save them to disk and then, as @r2evans suggested, run the command using `system`, maybe just `system("camcl.exe -sim *.lo")`.